# Swift 4 remove text from back button

Tags: swift, navigation, title, back-button

Guys i want to remove text from **Back** button.
i use this code to navigate from **VC1** to **VS2** (login form). I tried to add this code to VC2 but nothing.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
```

code:

```
@IBAction func didSelectSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    
    let vcName = vcNames[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]
    if vcName == "NQTPastRecordViewController" && loggined() == false {
        let alert = alertAskLogin({
            let signInVC = getController("EVSignInViewController")
            
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signInVC, animated: true)
        })
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        segmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        return
    }
    self.container.swipeToController(at: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways to achieve what you want to do.

When you push a view controller (VC2) onto the navigation stack for the first controller (VC1) the back button uses the title of the first screen by default as the back button title when the second screen is presented.

[image]

So in VC1 you could set the view controller's title to an empty string before you push onto the stack

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = ""
}
```

and this will leave you with a back button that just has the '<' character.

[image]

The second method is to set a custom back bar button item in the parent view controller (VC1)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

[image]

which sets the back button title to whatever you set in your UIBarButtonItem title field.

So your implementation might look something like this: (pick one option or the other where commented, if you do both the custom bar button item overrides the title.)

```
@IBAction func didSelectSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let vcName = vcNames[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]
    if vcName == "NQTPastRecordViewController" && loggined() == false {
        let alert = alertAskLogin({
            let signInVC = getController("EVSignInViewController")

            // set title to empty string here
            title = ""

            // or set a custom back bar button item and set target/action as needed
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

            navigationController?.pushViewController(signInVC, animated: true)
        })
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        segmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        return
    }
    container.swipeToController(at: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The back button text is the title of previous ViewController

i suggest you to change the previous ViewController title on viewDidDisapear method .

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution works for me:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backButtonTitle = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backImage"), style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector("action")) 
//action:#selector(Class.MethodName) for swift 4
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1
```

You can use the image for a back button if you wish or you can set a title to nil for UIBarButtonItem

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interface builder, you can select the navigation item of the previous controller and change the  Back Button string to what you'd like the back button to appear as. If you want it blank, for example, just put a space.

You can also change it with this line of code:

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Title here"];
```

Or in Swift:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
```

and to remove the back button text from the entire app use this :(Swift)

```
var navBarButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContained(in: UINavigationBar.self, nil)

navBarButtonAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```